# liquibase diff for a snapshot - error on parameter

Tags: liquibase

I am trying to generate the list off differences between a snapshot I created and the current DB.

I generated a snapshot  using the command:

```
liquibase --defaultSchemaName=common --outputFile=mySnapshot.json snapshot
```

and can see the json file in my directory.

However, when I try to execute the diff command, I get an error:

```
liquibase --url=jdbc:postgresql://10.1.7.17:5432/mydb --referenceUrl=offline:postgresql?snapshot=C:\liquibase-3.6.2-bin\mySnapshot.json  diff

Starting Liquibase at α, 14 ⌠ß° 2021 12:04:55 IST (version 3.6.2 built at 2018-07-03 11:28:09)
To display the help, please pass the '--help' option on the command line.
Unexpected error running Liquibase: Unexpected value '-url' (options must start with a '--')
liquibase.exception.CommandLineParsingException: Unexpected value '-url' (options must start with a '--')
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.parseOptions(Main.java:770)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:177)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:129)
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter, on windows at least, needs to be put into double quotes.
For example:

```
"--url=jdbc:postgresql://10.1.7.17:5432/mydb"
```